# How to navigate between listView options?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-listview

I have 1 listView with X options.

Each option refreshes this listView with other options (like a configuration menu).

My question is: how I can navigate back to the previous options?

I take the options from multiple  formatted html string in strings.xml

Whenever user click a row, I take the position and file from that row, I search that option and I clear/refresh all the rows.

I need a button to go back to the previous rows.

Here is an example:

```
 <string name="option1"><![CDATA[<menu>
<item>
    <body>option1_1</body>
    <target>lv</target>
    <file>option1_1</file>
</item>
<item>
    <body>option1_2</body>
     <target>lv</target>
    <file>option1_2</file>
</item>

<item>
    <body>option1_3</body>
     <target>wv</target>
    <file>option1_3.html</file>
    </item>
</menu>]]></string>

<string name="option1_2"><![CDATA[<menu>
    <item>
        <body>option2_1</body>
        <target>option2_1.html</target>
        <file>option2_1.html</file>
    </item>
    <item>
    <body>option2_2</body>
     <target>option2_2.html</target>
    <file>option2_2.html</file>
</item>   
</menu>]]></string>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At every node you create, you could create the reference to the parent. So when you create the child node, just initialise it from the parent node with its self. Then when you you're at a particular node, you could simply use the parent node for the listview.

Comment: I am populating it with a custom adapter.

I've done something like "tree structure" putting the target node in each option. I will have a lot of sublevels, The problem of your solution is that it's posible that 2 branches were in the same nodeLevel.

Comment: That's what I though!. I just wanted to compare my thoughts with other people. Thanks.

Comment: @Borja :) happy coding